# How do I insert some ProcessInstances for testing?

Tags: unit-test

I need to insert some ProcessInstances to run a few tests, how do I do that?

I did it that way:

```
ProcessInstance pi1 = new ProcessInstance(Status = 'Approved', TargetObjectId = recordId1);
ProcessInstance pi2 = new ProcessInstance(Status = 'Pending', TargetObjectId = recordId2);
insert p1;
insert p2;
```

But the console log responds:

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing:
>   [ProcessDefinitionId, CurrentNodeId]: [ProcessDefinitionId,
>   CurrentNodeId]

Which values should I define for ProcessDefinitionId and CurrentNodeId ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the way:

```
        Account acc1 = new Account(Name='acc1');
        insert acc1

        if([select count() from ProcessInstance where targetobjectid=:acc1.id] < 1)
        {       
            Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            req.setComments('Approve.');
            req.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});
            req.setObjectId(acc1.Id);

            //Submit the approval request
            Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req);

        }
```

Copied from: [NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS :No applicable process found!](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16214/no-applicable-process-no-applicable-process-found/16215#16215)

Answer (score 0):

This question and answer from the Salesforce.com Developer forum  might help [Errors with Unit Test for Approval Process Trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F0000000920bIAA)

Comment: Can you try this insert pi1;insert pi2;